# linux bc hexadecimal representation

Tags: linux, bc

I want to the following hexadecimals to be returned in 6 hex value format...

```
[admin@X~]$ echo "obase=16; 16777215" | bc
FFFFFF
[admin@X~]$ echo "obase=16; 0" | bc
0
[admin@X~]$
```

I want 0 be represented as 000000...

Any help?

Thanks,

Comment: Before you get too into this, what are you using them for?

Comment: I am trying to pass the output of this bc operation into a shell script to change the color of image... Look into http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/draw/#color and see that -fill argument should take 6 characters of hex values

Comment: I'd use `printf '%06X\n' 0`; `printf '%06X\n' 16777215` instead of bc for this job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

official answer then...

`printf` does hex with leading zeros easily and you don't need any of the fancy multi-precision math from `bc` so why not

```
printf '%06X\n' 0
printf '%06X\n' 16777215
```